# What does SELECT MIN(+ - Column) do?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I ran into a query today that did something I haven't seen before. It did something like this:

```
SELECT 
    MIN(+ - schema_id) AS [WhatInTheWorld?], 
    MIN(schema_id) AS MinimumID, 
    MAX(+ - schema_id) AS [Uhhh], 
    MAX(schema_id) AS MaxID
FROM sys.objects
```

Which gives the following results:

```
WhatInTheWorld? MinimumID    Uhhh       MaxID
-4              1            -1         4
```

What exactly are the "+" and "-" doing?

Comment: Where did you see this? it looks like it's just returning some schema_id's as negative numbers, but i have no idea why.

Comment: It was used in a way it was never meant to be used for sure. I saw it in reviewing old queries that I was rewriting and wanted to make sure what it was before i made any assumptions. To give an idea on the original query, mins were used everywhere because they did not know what a group by clause was. Only one of them had the min(- +) on it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`MIN(+ - schema_id)` is parsed as `MIN( + (- schema_id) )` which is the same as `MIN(- schema_id)`, so it's (mathematicaly)**<sup>*</sup>** the same as `-MAX(schema_id)`. Likewise for the MAX.

---

**<sup>*:</sup>** *<sup>There are some edge cases when the `MIN/MAX(-x)` might raise an error while the `- MAX/MIN(x)` will not (because the negation is applied in all values of the column vs only to the MAX/MIN value).</sup>*

Comment: `MIN(-x)` is almost identical to `-MAX(x)`, but there are some edge cases where they are different. See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/497cc/5 vs http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/497cc/4

Comment: @RazvanSocol yes, there are cases when one of the two will raise an error, because the negation is aplied only to the MIN/MAX value and not all the values of the column.